# setImageViewResource in Remote Views object pass an image using glide

Tags: android, widget, android-image, android-glide, remoteview

I am making a Widget and in the Widget service in the getViewAt method i have set corrently the text to my widget but it is complicated to pass my images from my object.

```
@Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
        Automoviles autoService=mArraylistAutomoviles.get(position);
        String imagen=autoService.getImagen();
        String marca =autoService.getMarca();


//        int imagenInt= Integer.parseInt(imagen);

        // Update the plant image
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image_item, R.drawable.mazda2azul);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView,marca);


        return views;

    }
```

Notice that in order to retreive the images i need to use Glide(Thats what i use in my project) .At the moment i have R.drawable.mazda2azul that is an int so the method doesnt complain .String imagen=autoService.getImagen return the following Url = https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/udacitycapstonefinal.appspot.com/o/CarImages%2Fford_escape_negra.jpeg?alt=media&token=89ea95d3-852c-4d24-9f09-b9ef519928a3

I tried to do 
  `int imagenInt= Integer.parseInt(imagen);` 
but it didnt load the widget images or Text .

So i need a way to do the Glide part and pass it to the 
setImageResource second parameter. This is my big problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setImageViewBitmap(int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)):

```
Bitmap bitmap = Glide.
    with(context).
    load(imagen).
    asBitmap().get();
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_image_item, bitmap);
```

Comment: Hello i added the asBitmap() after the with() and that made it work. But get() doesnt work. I checked other documentations and i dont see it anyware.          Bitmap imageBitmap=Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(imagen).get();

Comment: Its says cannot resolve method . it suggest getClass().

Comment: well, just find out how to load image into a bitmap with `Glide`, and us the last line after that